# Passing textfield values from one mxml file to other

Tags: apache-flex

I have following code that passes data from mxml file to a servlet, it works great
 I created the mxml file whose most important code is as follows:-
`<fx:Script>`
        `<![CDATA[`
            `public function abc():void`
            `{`
            `var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Srvlt");`
            `var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();`
            `variables.fn = fn.text;`
            `variables.ln = ln.text;`
            `variables.ea = ea.text;`
            `variables.pw = pw.text;`
            `request.data = variables;`
            `request.method = "POST";`
            `navigateToURL(request,'_self');`
            `}`
        `]]>`
    `</fx:Script>`
 this was the script code of the file and the main code is as follows:-
`<s:layout>`
        `<s:VerticalLayout/>`
    `</s:layout>`
    `<s:Form>`
        `<s:layout>`
            `<s:FormLayout gap="5"/>`
        `</s:layout>`
        `<s:FormItem label="First Name : ">`
            `<s:TextInput id="fn" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Last Name : ">`
            `<s:TextInput id="ln" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Email Address :">`
            `<s:TextInput id="ea"/>`
        `</s:FormItem>`
        `<s:FormItem label="Password :">`
            `<s:TextInput id="pw" displayAsPassword="true" />`
        `</s:FormItem>`
    `<s:FormItem>`
I am very much able to recieve these set of textfield's data from the mxml file to servlet but not getting a idea to pass them to another mxml file.

Answer (score 0):

1. The most elegant way. Use any MVC framework, like Robotlegs.
2. Use custom events dispatching.
3. (Fast but not "how it should be") Data binding. Here is the example:

`<s:TextInput id="sourceInput />`

`<s:TextInput text="{sourceInput.text} />`

Comment: what if i want to pick the source from the servlet, example i have a String fn = "John"; and String ln = "Watson"; in the servlet and i want to create a table on mxml for firstname and lastname. How would i do that?

Comment: You need to catch a result from your URLRequest. But in general, URLRequest is quite a low level API. As you are using Flex I would suggest using HTTPService component - it will provide better API for you: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html